# restrain jQuery UI draggable movement to arbitrary "enclosure"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a jQuery UI draggable of which I would like to constrain it's movement. If that movement is constrained to a parent container, that's supported as is. But what I need, is to constrain the movement to an "enclosed" box. To make it hopefully clearer an analogy: imagine you throw a ring over a pole. The ring's movement are then obviously limited by the pole it was thrown over.

What I have so far is a custom `drag` handler function, which kinda does the job, but has an annoying side-effect. I have to `return false` from it when I detect a collision and while that constrains the movement, it also stops the dragging. If I do not return false, the override of the position I'm doing simply has no effect.

I made a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dmrschmidt/u8u4qpdo/11/

In that fiddle I cannot even re-drag it again for some reason (it works on my actual page) but the code shows the idea.

Is there any way with jQuery UI or am I better off just rolling my own dragging function? I just like not re-inventing wheels.

[EDIT]

here's a screenshot to further illustrate my goal: https://s3.amazonaws.com/general-asset-catalogue/screenshot.png

The idea would be that the white box is draggable only in such a way, that the red box is always *inside* the white box. The red box itself is static.

Comment: Is there some reason you cannot use jQuery UI as it was designed? https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement

Comment: I've added a screenshot to clarify the difference. I'm basically trying to do the "opposite" of jQuery UI's default constrained movements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this Dennis, or explain why this isn't the right idea.

**Update**

Based upon your clarification, here is the solution. Easily tweeted to get perfect, but this is what you're after.

```js
let pole = $('#pole');
let ring = $('#ring');
let ringlt = pole.position();
let polelt = pole.position();
let containment = [ringlt.left - pole.outerWidth() / 2, ringlt.top - pole.outerHeight() / 2, ring.outerWidth() + pole.innerWidth() / 2, ring.innerHeight() + pole.outerHeight()];
$('#pole').draggable({
  containment: containment
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#pole {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  cursor: move;
}

#ring {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65px;
  left: 130px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="ring"></div>
<div id="pole">drag me</div>
```

Comment: I've added a comment with a screenshot to further clarify my goal. I want the movement to be constrained by an "inner box", not by an outer one. I guess I could dynamically create an invisible outer box with dimensions such that it seems like it's constrained to the inner one. But at that point I might as well implement my own draggable.

Comment: Or use an array of coordinates. Let me change my example when I get a chance.

Comment: Their docs only mention DOM elements (or an axis) as possible values for the `containment`. If it would also take simple coordinates that would at least make that "pseudo" approach a little more feasible.

Comment: Updated, please check.

Comment: Hah, yeah that's pretty much what I'm after! Great, thanks!

Comment: Great. Glad to help!